# Mobile Image Processing Web App

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm tasked with developing a mobile app with image processing and object recognition capabilities. The app must be able to recognize multiple objects of the same type within 5 seconds or so. Would a mobile app built with web technologies such as React Native, JavaScript, etc. be robust enough to handle this type of image processing and still provide a smooth user experience? If so, are there any libraries, frameworks, and/or tools you would suggest using to build this? Or would it be better to develop separate native iOS and Android apps?

I'm an electrical engineer with very little web (and) app development experience. Any suggestions or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Web app developing questions are off-topic on this site. Ref. [help/on-topic]. Please checkout [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)